# OpenCV - Record video in android with watermark

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg, android

Hi want to create a android app in which user can capture video. While capturing the video, a **watermark** should be shown in each frame, such that when the video is played afterwards it has an embedded watermark.

Has anyone worked on this before?

Comment: While questioning do not explicitly ask for code, First tell the community what you have done and then share the error you have faced.

Comment: Do visit [THIS POST](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/04/25/watermarking-images-with-opencv-and-python/) for more

Comment: I  already work with opencv image processing in android. But i need the same for videos ? Capture video and processing on each frames .

Answer (score 0):

To embed a watermark, you need to have an image with 4 channels namely: Red, Blue, Green and Alpha (transparency). All you have to do is extract this alpha channel and overlay it on top of the frames in the video.

*How do you overlay an image?*

Visit [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376337/applying-overlays-to-image-with-varying-transparency/41381887#41381887) where I have linked the solution.